# Правильно ли я обновляю datagridview

Tags: c#, update, datagridview, обновление

Привет всем, недавно начал использовать C# и наткнулся на несколько проблем, например обновить datagridview так что бы все осталось на своих местах(например: не соскролило наверх, выделенной осталась строка с которой работаем и тд). И начали терзать сомнения. После разных действий, например, добавить новую запись\редактировать текущую, я вызываю update_orders(); что бы после добавления увидеть сразу изменение в datagridview правильно ли я делаю?

```
    public void update_orders()
    {
            cn.Open();
            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            ds.Tables.Add(dt);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da = new SqlDataAdapter("тут запрос", cn);
            da.Fill(dt);
            bs.DataSource = dt;
            gridOrder.DataSource = bs;
            cn.Close();
```

}

Comment: Добавить gridOrder.DataBind() в самый конец и будет счастье

Comment: @nick_n_a мой проект это Win Forms, DataBind()  это для веба, или я ошибаюсь? Спасибо за ваш ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно это или нет, зависит от бизнес-логики приложения.

Если изменения в базе данных одновременно могут делать разные пользователи, то логично получать новые данные из БД.

Если только один пользователь работает с базой, то нет смысла получать оттуда те же самые данные. Впрочем, даже в этом случае это может понадобиться: при обновлении могут сработать триггеры (если они есть), может понадобиться получить значения ключей, сгенерированных базой, значения колонок по умолчанию, значения вычисляемых колонок.

---

Чтобы скролл DataGridView остался на том же месте, можно воспользоваться следущим:

```
int index = gridOrder.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex;

gridOrder.DataSource = bs;

gridOrder.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = index;
```

Comment: спасибо вам большое за помощь по скролу!!! По поводу бизнес логики, делаю апдейт только тогда, когда произошли изменения в таблицах связанных с этим datagridview. Апдейт мой происходит просто вот так update_orders(); например после insert. Почему я задал такой вопрос, у меня не получается настроить DgvFilterPopup или DataGridViewAutoFilter, по функционалу примерно одинаковые, проблема в том что после апдейта датагрида выставленные фильтры при помощи выше описанных библиотек сбиваются. Может вы знаете как сделать что бы не сбивались?

Comment: @Winteriscoming - Гм, это у вас какой-то сторонний датагрид, не родной DataGridView? Если да, то, наверное, стоит задать новый вопрос, указав, что это за компонент. Update: ага, нагуглил. Но подсказать вот так сходу ничего не могу.

Comment: нет это стандартный, просто подключается библиотека и становится доступным фильмы на столбцах. Я создал вопрос не на одном форуме никто ничего не знает. Я так понимаю мне нужно отловить имя столбца и значения выбранные на фильме и при апдейте пихнуть их в запрос и таким образом сохранится состояние datagridview. Правильно, или есть другой способ?

Comment: @Winteriscoming судя по исходникам DataGridViewAutoFilter, значения фильтров вы не сможете получить, методов для чтения и записи для них не предусмотрено. Но так как исходники доступны вы вполне можете добавить нужное сами, эта библиотека предоставляется для наглядной демонстрации или основы для модификаций. Цитата из описания - `The sample is not a full-featured, general-purpose, bug-free, nor Microsoft-supported solution, but it does provide a groundwork, which you can modify or use to guide your own implementation.`

Comment: @rdorn, спасибо. Значит не судьба мне его реализовать, открыл исходник и ничего не понял. Нужно дополнительный класс писать, при помощи которого можно было бы это определить?

Comment: @Winteriscoming необязательно, можно внести изменения в существующий. Там по идее одно свойство добавить, для доступа к фильтрам или пару методов типа import - export