# Выделить строку DataGridView после обновления

Tags: c#, datagridview, update

Есть `DataGridView` `dgv`,

```
 dgv.DataSource = myDateTable;
```

Есть код выделения строки

```
private static void SelectRowByOrderID(DataGridView dgv, string orderID)
    {
    dgv.Rows
             .OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
             .Where(x => (string)x.Cells["#"].Value == orderID)
             .ToArray<DataGridViewRow>()[0]
             .Selected = true;
    }
```

Действия:

- выбрать строку X;
- открыть форму редактирования;
- сохранить изменения в базе;
- закрыть форму редактирования;
- обновить таблицу `myDateTable`
- обновить `dgv.DataSource`

Вопрос:

- как после обновления `dgv` выделить строку Х ?

Comment: В чем проблема вызвать этот метод после обновления `dgv`?

Comment: не знаю на какое событие прописать

Comment: А где Вы `dgv.DataSource` обновляете? Почему нельзя сразу там выделить строки?

Comment: @AleksandrH. каким образом вы обновляете dgv? Напрямую dgv или через изменения myDateTable?

Comment: @Arantler, через изменение `myDateTable` (читаю с `OleDbDataReader`), не является `ObservalableCollection`. На данный момент решил так: после закрытия формы редактирования идет вызов метода который наново читает данные с БД, рисует грид, перемещает курсор на строку Х. Теперь вопрос: как не только переместить курсор на строку Х, но и чтобы после оновления грида востановился уровень вертикального скрола.

Comment: @AleksandrH.сохранять состояние скрола и номер последнего элемента, по которому кликали(или его Id). Чем же у вас является itemSource? List?

Comment: @AleksandrH. вот кстати в ответе на этот вопрос есть сохранение состояния скрола https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535737/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E-datagridview?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Если вы обновляете dgv через изменения DataSource **`И`** если myDateTable является ObservalableCollection **`И`**

то вас интересует ObservalableCollection.CollectionChanged
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подписываетесь на событие и выделяйте, что надо. Либо, если вас обычный event не устраивает, то создавайте свой и подписывайтесь на него.